# Can you store an email subject/body for a specific envelope type in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

Each envelope type will have its own email subject/body that is static for that envelope type. Here is an example of a few predetermined envelope types:

- Mortgage closing documents
- Mortgage loan application documents

These envelopes will contain a varied number of documents and each document is unique. I've attempted to create a template without a document, but it appears that is not allowed.

I'd like to be able to save the email body and subject for these envelope types so that when I send an envelope via the DocuSign API, I don't have to directly specify these fields. I'm hoping to avoid storing the subject/body inside of code or a configuration file. Preferably, I'd like a non-technical person to be able to change the subject/body through the DocuSign interface.

**What I ended up doing:**

---

Based on Kim Brandl's recommendations, I wrote the following code which worked as expected. A few notes:

1. The initial file that you added to the template will *not* appear in the final envelope if the ServerTemplate sequence is greater than the InlineTemplate. You can read more [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#composite-templates).
2. The Recipients, signers, documents, etc., follow the same pattern as a standard EnvelopeDefinition except the data is placed under the InlineTemplate.

   ```
   string docBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(file.Stream.ReadAsBytes());
   EnvelopeDefinition envDef = New EnvelopeDefinition();
   envDef.Status = "created";

   // The first sequence that appears will be the first document that is applied.
   // If you want the uploaded documents to appear instead of the server template,
   // make the server template a higher number.
   envDef.CompositeTemplates = new List<CompositeTemplate>
   {
       new CompositeTemplate()
       {
           ServerTemplates = new List<ServerTemplate>()
           {
               new ServerTemplate("2", templateId)
           },
           InlineTemplates = new List<InlineTemplate>()
           {
               new InlineTemplate()
               {
                   Sequence = "1",
                   Recipients = new Recipients()
                   {
                       Signers = new List<Signer>()
                       {
                           new Signer()
                           {
                               Email = request.Recipients[0].UserEmail,
                               Name = request.Recipients[0].UserName,
                               RoleName = request.Recipients[0].RoleName,
                               RecipientId = (1).ToString() 
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   Documents = new List<Document>()
                   {
                       new Document()
                       {

                           DocumentBase64 = docBase64,
                           DocumentId = "3",
                           Name = "ConsentFake.pdf",
                           IncludeInDownload = "true"
                       },
                       new Document
                       {
                           DocumentBase64 = docBase64,
                           DocumentId = "9",
                           Name = "ConsentFake2.pdf",
                           IncludeInDownload = "true"
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   };
   ```

Summary: This allowed me to take advantage of a DocuSign template's email subject/body without having to use a specific template document.

Comment: If you use New DocuSign experience then you can create template without adding document. But as Kim Brandl suggested create a template and then use Composite template to create an envelope by populating Subject and email body using Server Template and then adding document using Inline Template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a solution for the scenario that you've described by doing the following:

1. **Using the DocuSign web UI, [create a Template](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-create-templates) for each 'type of Envelope' and specify the Email Subject and Body in each Template that you create.** You'll also need to upload a document to the Template (DocuSign requires that you add at least one document before you can save the Template) -- but you can just add any placeholder doc (for example, a .txt file that contains the word *placeholder file*). The document you add to the template won't actually be used in the Envelopes that you create from the Template -- since you'll use the API to specify documents at runtime. (Non-technical folks will be able to use the DocuSign web UI to modify/update the email info in each Template at any point in the future.)
2. **When sending an Envelope via the API, use the `compositeTemplates` structure in the "Create Envelope" API request.** By using the `compositeTemplates` structure, you can specify the `serverTemplate` to use (which will pull in the Email Subject and Email Body that you've defined in that Template), specify recipient and tab info by using the `inlineTemplate` object, and specify document info using the `document` object.

(There's lots of info available here on Stack Overflow about how to use `compositeTemplates` in the **Create Envelope** request. If you have trouble getting that request structure correct/working, please post a separate question.)